# Elasticsearch analysis on field not working as intended

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm playing with ES 2.1 analyzers on the following index (aptly named my_index) :

```
$ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/' -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_synonym_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : [ "my_synonym_filter" ]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_synonym_filter" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [ "foo, bar" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            "properties" : {
                "my_field" : {
                   "type" : "string",
                   "analyzer" : "my_synonym_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The following analyses work as expected:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_synonym_analyzer&text=foo'
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?field=my_field&text=foo'

{
    "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "foo",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 3,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 0
    }, {
        "token" : "bar",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 3,
        "type" : "SYNONYM",
        "position" : 0
    } ]
}
```

However this one is not. I expect the same output as above, as stated in the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?field=my_type.my_field&text=foo'

{
    "tokens" : [ {
        "token" : "foo",
        "start_offset" : 0,
        "end_offset" : 3,
        "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position" : 0
    } ]
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in ES 2.0, [field names may not be prefixed with the type name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_type_name_prefix_removed) anymore, even though it used to work with pre-2.x releases of Elasticsearch.

So if you're using Elasticsearch 2.x, what you're observing is what you're supposed to get, i.e.

- analyzing with `field=my_field` works
- while analyzing with `field=my_type.my_field` does not anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using ES 2.1 and the `/my_index/_analyze?field=my_type.my_field` syntax comes from the doc. How do you specify the type to run the analysis against in that case ?

Comment: What you see in that doc (i.e. `obj1.field1`) is not a type name but the qualified name of a field within an object. In your case you simply need to use the field name, i.e. `field=my_field`, since you don't have any object in your mapping

Comment: And according to [Fields with the same name in different mapping types in the same index must have the same mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#field-conflicts) my last question is pointless.